# Hint View / Intro View on button click iOS for first time users

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8

I want to implement hints for the users who are going to visit my App for the first time. And when the users click on that a popup would appear like my screenshot which I have attached and explain the users about it. Any idea how to handle this.

[image]

Comment: @ Chandan You can display an image on button click and manage it using a BOOL variable

Comment: You need to persist the value to avoid showing it to old users. There are several ways to do so, check out this article [Detecting the first launch of the iOS application - the wrong and the right way](https://medium.com/anysuggestion/detecting-the-first-launch-of-the-ios-application-the-wrong-and-the-right-way-78b0605bd8b2#.ga7u7c5ec)

Comment: i think you want something like [this](https://github.com/tranquan/KJOverlayTutorial), check out this repo. I've implemented similar but with my own approach and my own class so cant share my code right now.